# Is there a simple way to implement gaussian process training in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, cloud, gaussian-process

I am wondering if there is a simple way to implement a GP training in parallel (with multi cores or even with multi instances for a cloud environment) with bayesian optimization.

`sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor` seems don’t support multi cores training. Its `n_restarts_optimizer` parameters controls the number of random restarts of the optimization in series.

Comment: found anything?